# como asignar el valor de una variable django a una variable en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, django, sweetalert

Saludos, tengo el siguiente problema con miaplicación django, utilizo swwetAlert para mostrar mensajes en mi interfaz web, pero quiero que el mensaje que se genera en mi vista django se muestre en mi template, para esto necesito almacenar en una variable javascript la información en una variable django, como podría hacer esto, en el código de abajo, la informaciónque tiene la variable menssage la quiero mostrar en el aviso,como puedo hacer esto.

```
{% if menssage %}
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
        sweetAlert({
            title: "Error!",
            text: menssage,
            type: "error",
            confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger',
            confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
        });
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre y cuando el archivo al en el cual quieres mostrar datos de Django o del servidor, sea un archivo que Django trate directamente, es decir, que pase por el motor de templates de Django y no sea generado por un framework del lado del front como Angular, React, Vue, etc. Es decir, siempre que tenga un contacto directo con django, puedes reemplazar del mismo modo que lo haces normalmente, en tu caso quedaría así:

```
{% if menssage %}
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    sweetAlert({
        title: "Error!",
        text: '{{ menssage }}',
        type: "error",
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn-danger',
        confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
    });
</script>
{% endif %}
```

Tienes que tener cuidado porque muchos de estos frameworks para tratar los templates suelen usar la misma sintaxis o nomenclatura que Django, como en el caso de Vue, que para reemplazar atributos o variables dentro del template también lo hace por medio de `{{` y `}}` y esto puede ocasionar problemas de renderizado de parte de Django.

Puedes pensar que sucede lo siguiente: Cuando tu vista retorna el render, django busca un archivo de `.html` el cual tu le pasaste por medio de la función, y junto a unos datos que le pasas por medio del `RequestContext`, el motor de templates de django empieza a buscar todas las coincidencias de `{{ }}` y hace un match del diccionario del `RequestContext` con la palabra que se encuentre entre las llaves, de esta forma reemplaza el contenido, y de no encontrar un match, simplemente la reemplaza por un string vacío.

Entonces, es importante recordar que a ese punto, nada de código de javascript puede ser ejecutado, ya que el motor de template de django no ejecuta el código del archivo html. Entonces cuando vaya a retornar dicho archivo al servidor, todas tus variables con `{{ }}` serán reemplazadas con un string vacío, y no te funcionará nada del javascript que interfiera con eso. Es algo complicado de explicar, espero haberme hecho entender por si tenías dudas.

Cualquier duda, pregunta :)

Comment: muchas gracias, era lo que andaba buscando